# PHP & MYSQLI selecting MySQL Table for Shop Items

Tags: php, mysql

For my school I need to Select items from the `MySQL Server` and it only should show the name and the price.

```
$sql = "SELECT `item`,`price` FROM `items` ";
$query = mysqli_query(con(), $sql); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

foreach($row as $values)
{
    echo "<p>".$values["item"]."</p>";
    echo "<p>".$values["price"]."</p>";
}
```

I only got something like:

```
L

L

L

L

4

4

4

4
```

Its the only first item in the table but there are many rows in `DB`.

Comment: you need to mark it as answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT `item`,`price` FROM `items` ";
$query = mysqli_query(con(), $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo "<p>".$row["item"]."</p>";
    echo "<p>".$row["price"]."</p>";
}
```

Comment: @Kira please accept an correct answer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

you're doing fine, but what you're doing wrong is, *you're picking just one item and iterating over that single value*.

Here you're extracting only *LLLL4444* and looping on this only, so, in order to get all.

You need to do this.

```
$sql = "SELECT `item`,`price` FROM `items` ";
$query = mysqli_query(con(), $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    echo "<p>".$row["item"]."</p>";
    echo "<p>".$row["price"]."</p>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_array()` essentially returns two arrays one with numeric index, one with associative string index.

So using `mysql_fetch_array()` without specifying `MYSQL_ASSOC` or `MYSQL_NUM`, or by specifying MYSQL_BOTH will return two arrays